# I cant use HTTPREQUEST Class in php

Tags: php, httprequest

I'm using xampp 1.8.1 on windows xp home edition and TS,VC9 and my php version is 5.4.7.

I did all thing even add php_http.dll in extension and add extension in `php.ini` but I could not use `httprequest` class
errors:

```
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\pear\HTTP\Request.php on line 412

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\pear\HTTP\Request.php on line 736

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\pear\HTTP\Request.php on line 749

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\pear\HTTP\Request.php on line 794

Strict Standards: Redefining already defined constructor for class Net_URL in C:\xampp\php\pear\Net\URL.php on line 124

Fatal error: Class 'HttpRequest' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\crawl\index.php on line 4
```

Comment: Use [this](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2).

Comment: i tried  it but not work

Comment: Could you edit your post to show how you tried it?

Comment: use curl instead, like [this snippet][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31318117/1166727