# "PHP Fatal error: Class 'HttpRequest' not found"

Tags: php, httprequest, osx-lion, pecl

I've been stuck trying to solve this problem in many ways, reading a lot of posts but still having no luck.
I work on a Mac, OSX 10.7 Lion, and I'm writing a plugin for a WordPress site (php files) using MAMP, and at one point I have to make an HTTP request:

```
$request = new HttpRequest('something'); 
$request->setMethod(HTTP_METH_GET);
```

There's an error when executing this request and when I checked the log file, here's the message:

```
"PHP Fatal error:  Class 'HttpRequest' not found in (the_php_file)"
```

I've already installed PEAR, PECL and the HTTP extension (pecl_http), Xcode and its command line tools. 
This is what I did:

- modified the PATH:

  ```
  $ echo "export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.profile`
  ```
- verified that the paths for php, pear and pecl are correct:

  - /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/php  is the path for php
  - /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/pear for pear
  - /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/pecl for pecl
- I downloaded the source for php from the MAMP page (and checked that the version I  downloaded was the same one I'm using, which is php5.5.3). Then I extracted the content and put it into /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/include/php
- Inside /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/include/php I ran `./configure`
- I executed: `pecl install pecl_http`
- I also added these extensions to the php.ini (initially, I modified the  MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/conf/php.ini file):

  ```
  extension=raphf.so
  extension=propro.so
  extension="http.so"
  ```

About that last one in quotation marks: when I added the extension manually, I did it like this: `extension=http.so`. Then (when trying to fix my problem) I tried an alternative installation that modified the php.ini automatically, and wrote the extension with the quot. marks, but the result was still the same, so it didn't make a difference.

After all of this, I stopped the MAMP server and started it again, but when I executed the php  I still got the error (visible in the php_error.log):

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'HttpRequest' not found
```

I've been following this guide mostly, among so many more:
http://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/installing-php-pear-and-pecl-extensions-mamp-mac-os-x-107-lion

I'd appreciate any idea because I've run out of them.

Comment: Did you find the solution for your question?

Answer (score 26):

The class HttpRequest is provided by **v1** of this PECL extension.

Re-install via: `$ pecl install -f pecl_http-1.7.6`

You can find documentation for **v2** here, though:
https://mdref.m6w6.name/http

Comment: I execute this command but get the error : `No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/pecl_http"` How should I fix this, bro?

Comment: Depends on your PHP version. Append the appropriate pecl_http version compatible with your PHP version.

Answer (score 3):

alternatively, in case you cannot control certain environmental variables or install packages, you might try using curl which should return a json object (below is a working snippet of a google api call).

```
$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=TOKEN_DATA_123';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($response, true);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($json);
$userEmail = $json["email"];
```